# HTML5 Canvas Pulsate

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

I am looking for a method that given x[], y[] as coordinates on a canvas, it would draw a pulsating rings on the pair of (x, y).

```
.gps_ring {
    border: 3px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    opacity: 0.0
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

Similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/HQV6m/

I really don't want to place divs on top of canvas and so I am hoping for a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use easing functions to "pulse" a highlight ring.

Here is an example and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JYP8T/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    // set the context styles
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.strokeStyle="gold";
    ctx.fillStyle="#888";

    // variables used to draw & animate the ring
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    var ringX,ringY,ringRadius,ingCounter,ringCounterVelocity;

    // fill the canvas with a background color
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    // tell handleMouseDown to handle all mousedown events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    // set the ring variables and start the animation
    function ring(x,y){
        ringX=x;
        ringY=y;
        ringRadius=0;
        ringCounter=0;
        ringCounterVelocity=4;

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // the animation loop
    function animate(){

        // return if the animation is complete
        if(ringCounter>200){return;}

        // otherwise request another animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // ringCounter<100 means the ring is expanding
        // ringCounter>=100 means the ring is shrinking
        if(ringCounter<100){ 
            // expand the ring using easeInCubic easing
            ringRadius=easeInCubic(ringCounter,0,15,100); 
        }else{ 
            // shrink the ring using easeOutCubic easing
            ringRadius=easeOutCubic(ringCounter-100,15,-15,100);
        }

        // draw the ring at the radius set using the easing functions
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ringX,ringY,ringRadius,0,PI2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        // increment the ringCounter for the next loop
        ringCounter+=ringCounterVelocity;
    }


    //  Robert Penner's easing functions
    //
    //  https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js
    //
    //  now=elapsed time,
    //  startValue=value at start of easing,
    //  deltaValue=amount the value will change during the easing,
    //  duration=total time for easing

    function easeInCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
      return deltaValue*(now/=duration)*now*now + startValue;
    }
    function easeOutCubic(now, startValue, deltaValue, duration) {
      return deltaValue*((now=now/duration-1)*now*now + 1) + startValue;
    }


    // handle mousedown events
    function handleMouseDown(e){

      // tell the browser we'll handle this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // calc the mouse position
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // animate a ring at the mouse position
      ring(mouseX,mouseY);

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Click in the canvas to draw animated circle with easings.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the animation continuous and also draw multiple rings (with animation).. Last, if there's an image on the canvas and the rings are being drawn and animated, would that decrease the performance? Thanks

Comment: **Continuous:** set ringCounter back to zero when it reaches 200. **Multiple rings:** Sure, just draw multiple arcs with different radii. **Performance:** Depends on what else needs to be redrawn on the canvas. Arcs are a primary shape for canvas so not a big performance hit there. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Mark I really appriciate your help with this. I made the changed as you proposed but ran into an issue. Upon setting the ringcounter back to 0 to enable looping, the speed of the circles increase once you click on a second location on the canvas. Here's what I mean: (click on two locations)  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYP8T/8/)

Comment: You have to cancel the animation of the first ring if you want to start a different ring:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2C5xq/